# Error VBA connection string to GCP server (SQL Server 2019 Standard)

Tags: sql-server, vba, google-cloud-platform, database-connection

I'm a unexperienced Google Cloud user and I want to connect a local Access macro to my SQL database on my Google Cloud.
So, I have created a Google Cloud enviroment with a database on the Google Cloud Server.
Everything works fine there. I checked all the permissions, users etc. I can create reports, make selections etc.

But when I want to connect my Access macro I get an error message:
'SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. '

Seems to me that Google has problems with the Instance name (by the way, which contains the character ':').
But I copied this Instance name from my Google Console: 'horizontal-leaf-391110:europe-west4:brainsql'

The VBA code looks like:

```
    Server_Name = "xx.xx.xxx.xx\horizontal-leaf-391110:europe-west4:brainsql" 
    Database_Name = "TESTDATA" 
    User_ID = "myUser" 
    Password = "myPassword" 
   
    
    With connection
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Server=" & Server_Name & ";database=" & Database_Name & ";User Id=" _
        & User_ID & ";Password=" & Password & ";"
        .ConnectionTimeout = 10
        .Open
    End With
```

I tried several Providers (apart from MSOLEDBSQL) and several Instance names, but I failed everytime.

Can anybody tell me how to solve this issue? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possibly you are confusing GCP's horribly named "Instance connection name" field with the instance name for an SQL Server. Have you tried using just the IP address?

Comment: I just tried, but I got another error: 'Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]'

Comment: The named pipes provider needs a bunch more ports open than are likely available through GCP. Why aren't you using the TCP/IP provider? Have you tried `Server=tcp:xx.xx.xxx.xx,1433;` (or whatever your port number is) in your connection string?

Comment: We are getting closer now! No waiting time anymore, but an immediate reaction. Unfortunately still an error: 'Cannot open database "brain" requested by the login. The login failed.'

Comment: If you have access to the SQL Server instance you can check the SQL Server Logs node to see why the login is failing. Look for the Error 18456 events, take note of the `State` numbers they reference and compare them against those listed at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to determine the cause of the login failure. Probably the password is incorrect (they're case sensitive), or the login doesn't have a corresponding Database User created for it in the database you're trying to access.

Comment: I now changed to user: slqserver with a new password. That worked! Thanks.